# Create button in Facebook API to show/hide (toggle)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, button, toggle

I am using the Facebook Javascript API. I want to create something like this:

```
1. Album Name [show/hide]

Album details

2. Album Name [show/hide]

Album details

3. Album Name [show/hide]

Album details
```

1. First I retrieved the list of albums
2. There would be a button beside the album name to toggle (show/hide) details of albums using jQuery.
3. The album details are put into p tags with specific IDs ("album1", "album2", etc...)
4. Using jQuery to toggle the specific IDs.
5. However, button in1 created inside the FB.api is not able to toggle.
6. Another button out1 which is out of the FB.api is able to toggle.

QNS: Why is it that the button inside the FB.api is unable to do the toggling?

I just wish to make a specific button for each album so I can toggle each album's details specifically.

Partial code below:

```
<script>
    function albums()
    {

    FB.api('me/albums/', function(response) {
      for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
        var album = response.data[i]; // each album

        // Album Name
        var albumName = response.data[i].name;
        var para = document.createElement('p');
        var node = document.createTextNode(albumName);
        para.appendChild(node);
        document.body.appendChild(para); // put p into body of document

        // Button
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "in"+(i+1);
        var t = document.createTextNode("inside");      
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);  


        // Album Details
        var para = document.createElement('p');
        para.id = "album"+(i+1);
        var node = document.createTextNode("Album details");
        para.appendChild(node);
        document.body.appendChild(para);
        }   


    });
    }
</script>   

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<button id="out1">out1</button>
<script>
jQuery( "#out1" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#album1" ).toggle();
});
jQuery( "#in1" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#album1" ).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to put an even listener on an element that is loaded asynchronously. Meaning, the button does not exist yet. Make sure you know what asynchronous means, it´s very important to know for a JavaScript developer and especially when working with the Facebook JS SDK. And add an event listener to a button right after creating/showing the button.

Also, keep in mind that you would put an event listener on the very first button only.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll read up more on asynchronous. So how can I create the button listener?

Comment: either right after creating the button - which would result in a lot of event listeners - or right after the for loop ($('.yourbuttonclass').click..., for example). even better: don´t use jquery at all for those simple things. there is "addEventListener", native javascript stuff.

Comment: the main thing is that your button is not created when you try to add the event listener. how to program it correctly is up to you, there are many ways to solve this. try to understand the code, that´s always important. if you understand how everything works, it´s easy.